# How can I reuse the API data for all the pages in react js

Tags: reactjs

I'm a newbie in react js. I am building a 4-5 pages website using react js. In all the pages, there is an API called category. What is the best way to request this API once and use the same data for all pages where needed? I tried to find on google but did not come to a satisfactory result so your guide will help to save the client resource to call the same API for every component or pages again and again.

thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Put the data into Local Storage

Comment: This is the best way? what about context API in react js?

Comment: Context is for when data needs to be used in deeply nested components without explicitly passing it. But keeping the data persistent over multiple pages requires something entirely different.

Comment: Well, you call the API in the  `App.js` then pass the API data as props to the pages or Use REDUX

Comment: Thanks, @KALITA, as I read, may redux is used for a complex website. I have only 4-5 pages with different APIs. The category API is used on every page. So its best to use redux in my app as well?

Comment: @GauravNarula Well why not try it !! You will get to know new stuff and will help in your upcoming projects

Comment: Thanks, @KALITA, I will but right now my project is on deadline. I have 1 or 2 days only to deliver the project. This is the only problem in my project I have noticed yesterday.

Comment: Context API / or some state management library like redux.

Comment: Thanks, @Tuhin I believe Context may help only when components are nested only. Isn't it? I can think for redux but project is on deadline as I have only 1-2 days.

Comment: Then go for redux. it will be the faster approach.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question depends on what scope of resistance you want. If you want to redo the API call every reload, then you can use something like Redux to share the output across multiple components. If you want it to be stored for longer, you can use LocalStorage. Do note that you can also use LocalStorage if you want to only store temporarily, but you need to add code so that you get data from the API during application load.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Category API data is not temporary data. It contains images and some category related information to show on some pages like on product pages and based on its use will redirect on some specif page.

Comment: If this was the answer you were looking for, you can mark it as such with the tick mark below the votes.

Answer (score 2):

For better handling fetch data and caching it for next use , you can easily use two powerful library

`react-query` 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-query

Or

`swr` https://swr.vercel.app/

They can manage your fetched data and store it for you, in next use if they have your data it return cached instance of your data

Update :

If you want to save your data after reloading page you can use two useful library that can save your state to localStorage

for simple states yo can use :

`use-persisted-state` https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-persisted-state

and for complex state can use :

`use-persisted-reducer`

https://github.com/khakestani/use-persisted-reducer

https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-persisted-reducer

Comment: Using this library is very enjoyable and on the other hand eliminates the worries of using Redux @GauravNarula

Answer (score 1):

There could be two ways I can think of -

1. Use higher Order Components or Render Props pattern. This will extract the API call logic into a single place and then you can wrap your components to get the data. For more, you can dig in docs https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html
2. Use Redux and thunk to leverage store and actions. you can find redux docs over here https://redux.js.org

Comment: Thanks for your response @sunny I think redux will help me in this case only. I am using react js with webpack so it is easy to integrate with redux as well? thanks

Comment: Yes, You definitely can. In fact, I have my repository which is built with webpack, react, and redux. See if it helps you. https://github.com/sprakash57/webpack-react-saga.